# Cannot install Windows WDK on Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio, wdk, windows-dev-center

I am trying to install WDK and alternatively Windows Standalone Developmet Kit on two separate windows 10 PC's and it failes on both.

The log says: "Hash mismath for path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache....

It happened multiple times, even after deleting all files in "package Cache" folder. 
Is there any solution to this? It seem it's just impossible to download WDK at all... Is there any resolution to this? Is there anyway I can just download the ISO and install from there?

Comment: I see your question has been answered at SU forum and I will add the [link](http://superuser.com/questions/1152478/windows-10-sdk-download-fails-hash-mismatch) here to share with more community member. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was double posted and answered elsewhere.

Comment: Would do that myself but the duplicate link is on superuser (stack exchange site) but not stackoverflow...